# Cloud PubSub quotas for "Push subscriber throughput" do not apply if set too low

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

We tried to enforce a certain rate limit on Cloud PubSub Push Subscrber by setting the quota on "Push subscriber throughput, kB" to 1, effectively meaning that PubSub should process no more than 1 kbps with the push subscriber.

However, the actual throughput can be higher than that, around to 6-8 kbps.

Why is that not limiting the throughput as expected?

More details:

The goal is to have a rate limit of 50 messages per second.

We can assume the average message size, for the purposes of our testing we use 50 bytes messages, which is 50 bytes * 60 second = 3000 bytes per second, or 3 kbps for a message every second. By setting the quota to 1 we expected to get way less than 50 messages per second pushed by PubSub. During testing we got signiticantly more than that.

Comment: I'm afraid there is an issue with your test calculations. If each second you send 60 messages with 50 bytes each, that is 3 kB per second. If you send a message every second, that would be 50 bytes per second, or 0.05 kBps. Which throughput do you have in your tests, 3 or 0.05 kBps?
Also, by "the actual throughput can be higher than that, around to 6-8 kbps" you still mean the Push subscriber throughput, right? Consider that, for quota usage measurements, Cloud Pub/Sub rounds up the size of each request to 1 kBps, which might be an obstacle for testing such small message sizes.

Comment: Docs here (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#quota_units ) about my previous statement.

Comment: We actually want to send 50 messages per second, so you're right that my calculations are not correct. The right version would be (50 bytes) * (50 messages) = 2500 bytes total; that's 2.5 kbps, but when we set the pubsub quota to 1 kbps, the actual throughput is more than that (6-8 kbps).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is a known issue with the enforcement of push subscriber quota in Google Cloud Pub/Sub.

In general, push subscriber quota is not really a good way to try to enforce flow control. For true flow control, it is better to use pull subscribers and the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#message-flow-control). The goal of flow control in the subscriber is to prevent the subscriber from being overwhelmed. In the client library, flow control is defined in terms of outstanding messages and/or outstanding bytes. When one of these limits is reached, Cloud Pub/Sub suspends the delivery of more messages.

The issue with rate-based flow control is that it doesn't account well for unexpected issues with the subscriber or its downstream dependencies. For example, imagine that the subscriber receives messages, writes to a database, and then acknowledges the message. If the database were suffering from high latency or just unavailable for a period of time, then rate-based flow control is still going to deliver more messages to the subscriber, which will back up and could eventually overload its memory. With flow control based on outstanding messages or bytes, the fact that the database is unavailable (which prevents the acknowledgement of messages by the subscriber) means that delivery is completely halted. In this situation where the database cannot process any messages or is processing them extremely slowly, sending more messages--even at a very low rate--is still harmful to the subscriber.